# MySQL: Create View with Join and calculated field

Tags: mysql

Given two tables joined by a foreign key where one document can have many doc_line_items:

```
documents     doc_line_items
--------     -------------
 id            id
 overview      doc_id(FK)
 doc_number    unit_price
               quantity
```

I need to construct a view that only returns the document number, overview and grand total of all line items attached to it. If, for example, document 1 has three line items:

```
doc_line_items
--------------
id doc_id    unit_price    quantity
-- ------    ----------    --------
1   1          1.00           5
2   1          5.00           2
3   1          2.00           1
```

I need the view to output the following:

```
document_view
-------------
doc_number    overview    grand_total
----------    --------    -----------
  1            stuff       17.00
```

I need this output for every document in the database. The best I've been able to do so far is to join the tables together and pull in the raw data:

```
 CREATE VIEW doc_joined_view AS
 SELECT documents.id, documents.msr_number, documents.overview, 
 doc_line_items.msr_id, doc_line_items.quantity, doc_line_items.unit_price 
 FROM documents 
 INNER JOIN doc_line_items on documents.id = doc_line_items.msr_id;
```

How can I change the above to get my desired view?

Comment: Add a group by on doc_number and sum the quantity column.

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I needed.